# How to add event listener with jQuery and multiple buttons with same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an "event listener" with jQuery to buttons that are created from loading data from database. I can get it to work with JavaScript but trying to get it to work with jQuery. I need the following code in jQuery.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <tr>
        <td class="fName"><?php echo $row['eFirstName'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['storeName'] ?></td>
        <td>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" <?php if($row['eActive'] == 1){echo "checked";} ?> class='isActive'>
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="edit-employee.php?id=<?php echo $row['employee_id'] ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" >Edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</form> 








var isActive = document.getElementsByClassName('isActive');
        var fName = document.getElementsByClassName('fName');
        
        for(let i =0; i <isActive.length; i++ ){
            
            isActive[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                fName[i].classList.add('bg-danger');
            })
```

I have tried plain JavaScript and used a for loop to target specific button which works but can't figure it out with jQuery.

Comment: What have you tried in jQuery? Please include that in your post. Where did it go wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: I have tried this: 
`
$('.isActive').each(function(i, item){
    $(this).on('click', function(){     
     
     console.log(i);
    })
   })
`


Which gives me the index number but from there I can't figure out how to bind that to for example fName class to change its background color like I did with plain JS.

Comment: Where are you running into problems translating into JQuery?? I'm not super familiar with it.